# Intraday "Time to expiration" for Black-Scholes on the expiration day

Tags: option-pricing, black-scholes, european-options, expiration

In Black-Scholes, T is the % of year, how do we calculate T intraday on the expiration day?

Does the expiration happen at the exact moment of that trading session?

For example, for SPXW options that expire on Friday Jan 8th when the trading stops at 15:15 CST, at 9:15 AM CST on that day, is T=(6hours/24hours)/365=0.0006849?